DCS RDU366 oven not heating
I have a dual fuel DCS RDU366. To run the oven, two knobs are turned: the left one controls the function (Bake/Convection Bake/&c), another to its right controls the temperature. A "halo" light around each knob indicates if a knob is active.
The left knob halo lights when turned to "BAKE". The right knob's halo does not light up, nor does the oven temperature change.
My guess: the heating element is busted. But I can't find a service manual for this model.
Any assistance greatly appreciated, to short-circuit (haha) my time spent pulling this thing out from the wall, &c.

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/985004/Dcs-Rgu-366.html?page=39#manual
